# Are nested resources RESTful?

Tags: api, rest

How architecturally sound and up to industry standards nesting resource representations in REST APIs is, especially when it comes to nested lists of resources (like books of an author)?

I'm interested in finding links to authoritative sources that answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The authoritative source for [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) of Roy Fielding, based on work he did during the standardization of HTTP/1.1 ([RFC 2068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2068), [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616), etc) in the 1990s.

REST defines [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) ("Any information that can be named can be a resource..."), and requires that all resources understand messages the same way ([uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)) but does not actually constrain your resource model.

"RESTful", historically, is context sensitive; in practice it means something like "more like REST than our current designs".  In the web services community, it meant "more like REST than WS-* and SOAP".  In Rails, it meant more like REST than the resource models that were recommended prior to Rails 1.2.  And so on.

---

If what you are interested in is describing the relationship between a resource that is a collection and a resource that is an item in that collection, then the standard you want is [RFC 6573](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573.html).

But again, it doesn't tell you how to design the resources, or how to design the identifiers for those resources -- it just tells you how to indicate a relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the web resource is something abstract identified by the IRIs and accessible through the web. What dereferencing the IRI gives back is the representation of the actual state of the identified resource, this is why it is called representational state transfer. I don't remember any standard that discusses nested resources. Maybe RDF is the closest what you are looking for. In practice if we follow RDF concepts, then to answer a GET request the REST API responds with a representation of an RDF subgraph starting with the resource indentified by the giving IRI and it can be any level deep. Nestedness is not something I would consider here, because it is a graph, not a hierarchy, it is sort of expanding relationships between resources or returning hyperlinks the API consumers can follow to do the exact same thing.

Not sure if this helps. I did not find any RFC beyond what VoiceOfUnreason's answer contains, I remember to read explicitly about web resources and identifying real things with hashtags or non-dereferenceable IRIs in an RFC 5+ years ago, but I have no idea which one it was. Maybe it was the [Lanthaler dissertation](https://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf) or the [SemWeb document](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#semweb) VoiceOfUnreason suggested. What is certain it was somehow connected to the semantic web and RDF.

> REST’s identification of resources constraint requires that resources
> are identifiable so that they can be accessed and manipulated via
> generic interfaces. On the Web, resources are identified by IRIs [44].
> Since a resource may represent con- cepts which cannot be serialized
> into a byte stream (e.g., persons or a feeling), resources are not
> manipulated directly. Instead, REST is built on the concept of
> manipulation of resources through representations; i.e., an additional
> layer of indirection in the form of resource representations is
> introduced.

https://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf

> On the Semantic Web, all information has to be expressed as statements
> about resources, like the members of the company Example.com are Alice
> and Bob or Bob's telephone number is "+1 555 262" or this Web page was
> created by Alice. Resources are identified by Uniform Resource
> Identifiers (URIs) [RFC3986]. This modelling approach is at the heart
> of Resource Description Framework (RDF) [RDFPrimer]. A nice
> introduction is given in the N3 primer [N3Primer].
>
> Using RDF, the statements can be published on the Web site of the
> company. Others can read the data and publish their own information,
> linking to existing resources. This forms a distributed model of the
> world. It allows the user to pick any application to view and work
> with the same data, for example to see Alice's published address in
> your address book.

https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#semweb

So what I want to say that what you see in the HTTP response is not the resource itself, just a representation of it and its relationship to other resources.

REST does not have a constraint which tells you how verbose that response must be. It just tells you that you must use hyperlinks to connect resources and that you must use standard MIME types and document your API. At least this is how I interpret the uniform interface constraint.

I think the question is very good, because this part of the architecture is open and there were many questions in the past years which ask how to use the URIs for querying nested resources. The answer is always that REST does not cover it, the URI and URI template standards don't cover it either. There are standards like OData and Hydra, which have suggestions, but it is just up to you. Your problem is connected to it, because it asks how verbose a response to such a query can be. It is not covered as well as far as I can tell, but what is certain that it can and must contain at least hyperlinks to other resources. RDF allows describing several resources in a single document, so if we extend the RDF approach to REST, which does not say this is forbidden, then I guess we can do it.

From practical perspective for example a collection is a sort of nested resource too and if the API consumer would send a dedicated request for every collection item just to know basic things like product names, then it would be wasting resources. Normally we respond this kind of requests with a single HTTP response or multiple ones with 25-50-100 items on a page. It does not make much sense from usability and scalability perspective to give hyperlinks to the consumer for each item and force them to follow those links one by one. In fact we like to respond with the exact view model the consumer needs and design APIs this way. I think the same is true for nested properties as well. From RDF perspective these responses represent a subgraph of a massive resource graph, which are managed by the REST service and by for example RDF vocabulary maintainers like OWL, Schema.org, etc.

So to have a one sentence answer: the representation of "nested resources" is not covered by REST and as far as I know not covered by standards like HTTP and URI either, but currently it is the best practice to use them and MIME types we frequently use for REST e.g. HAL+JSON or RDF/JSON-LD support nested representations too, so I would say yes.

Comment: Perhaps: https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#semweb ?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason It was something similar, but I don't know. Thanks for the link btw. I'll save it.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Maybe it was the Lanthaler dissertation: https://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/third-generation-web-apis-bridging-the-gap-between-rest-and-linked-data.pdf It is a fine read if somebody likes REST.

Comment: @inf3rno, thanks a lot for such details, bounty is on me (as soon as it is available for the question).